# Python3: How do I save a text file with a name from an input?

Tags: python

This is the line of code:

```
with open('directory/filename.txt', 'w') as output:
```

How do I make

```
filename = input("Write the output file's name :")
```

Work for the code above ?

Comment: You need to be clearer with what you are asking. Give an example.

Comment: Got it

> open('directory/{}.txt').format(filename), 'w')

Answer (score 2):

Join the inputted file name with `os.path.join()` with the directory:

```
import os

filename = input("Write the output file's name: ")

with open(os.path.join('directory', filename), 'w') as output:
   # work on file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a file object by directly inputting a filename into the open() parameters

```
 file = open(input("Enter Filename: "),'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> with open(input('fname:\n').split('.txt')[0]+'.txt','w') as f:
...     f.write('test')
...
fname:
testy
```

In this case, even if the user enters or doesn't enter the file extension, it will be added.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic way:

```
directory = "directory"
filename = input("Name of file")
with open(directory + "/" + filename, "w") as output: # You could also do f"{directory}/{filename}" or use .format
    # do_something()
```

But I would prefer something like:

```
with open(pathlib.Path(pathlib.Path(directory) / filename), "w") as output:
    # do_something()
```